# Noticing "score" and "answers" bars after unlocking "access to site analytics"

Tags: support

I just passed 25,000 rep, and now have access to site analytics.

On my profile summary tab, I see the following...

[image]

What does the new **score** and **answers** numbers mean?

This "new" score/answers bars have never appeared on my summary page before. How does one change the "Next tag badge", or is it static?

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: what took you so long? >:-D

Comment: Thank you for all of the kind responses. This "new" score/answers bars have never appeared on my summary page before... so I thought it was related to site analytics. How does one change the "Next tag badge", or is it static?

Comment: @heynnemaUnder wher5e it says Next Tag Badge is a little cog, click that and you can set ther badge to the one you want to track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following question is raised in [a comment by OP](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18725/site-analytics-question#comment40013_18725):

> This "new" score/answers bars have never appeared on my summary page before... so I thought it was related to site analytics. How does one change the "Next tag badge", or is it static?

You didn't see this before because the site lets you track *either* a **[tag badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges)** *or* the next **[privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges)** to be unlocked and I'm pretty sure previously it was tracking privileges in your profile, something like this:
[image]

By reaching 25k, you have unlocked the last possible privilege, viz. '*access to site analytics*'. Since there is no more privileges to track, the system has switched to tracking a tag badge instead and picked [virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) for being the most likely next in the queue (as per some algorithm).

As far as I know you cannot disable this feature. You can however pick a different tag to track by clicking the cogwheel next to tag being tracked currently (cogwheel next to [virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) as in [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAgJx.png)).

Answer (score 5):

These two bars have nothing to do with the 25k analytics privilege, they are visualizing your progress towards the tag badge you're currently tracking.

In your case, that's currently the [virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) tag. A score of 100 upvotes over at least 20 answers is the requirement for a bronze tag badge.

All this selection does is to pick one badge for which you can see the progress directly on your profile page. All others can be accessed and selected instead by clicking on the cog symbol next to the badge, as seen on your screenshot.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how long that feature already exists, but I'd guess it has to be at least one or two years... You should probably have seen it before already.

Comment: The reason this area toggled automatically to show progress towards the next tag badge, and hence it correlated with the site analytics privilege, is that heynema got the last privilege available so there are no more privileges to track. By default it tracks next privilege, but the user can toggle it to track next tag badge instead, and pick a tag badge too (I've been tracking the MATE tag  badge since i installed MATE, and got several tag badges in the meantime)

Comment: @Zanna Oh yes, of course. Now that you mention it, I remember. You have the option to track either progress for the next privilege (default) or for a tag badge. It has been a while since my last unlocked privilege ;)

Comment: @Zanna I didn't see your comment before and posted an answer pointing out the same thing. Hope you don't mind :p

Comment: @pomsky of course not :) thanks for your effort and +1

Answer (score 3):

That's your [virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) tag badge progress and has nothing to do with the site analytics.  **0:-)**  You just went looking for something new and never noticed this one before *until now*...

Just click on [virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) and you can put *one of* a number of badge progresses there...

BTW:

### Congratulations on being 25K rep and being in the top 1000 of users!¹

<sub>**Note 1:** Top 0.12% is top 1000</sub>

Comment: Of course you love to waste precious vertical screen real estate again >:D Anyway, "you can put any number of badge progresses there" is wrong, the UI only allows one tracked badge at a time.

Comment: Smiley removed @ByteCommander and text adapted to be more precise!  **;-) :P**

Comment: Thanks for the congrats!

Answer (score 3):

- score is the total of non-wiki answers for a tag (virtualbox). So each time you answer a question with a tag it goes up by 1.
- answers the total points you gained for that score

100/20 gets you a bronze badge for it but only gold is important 1000/200. Gold gets you the privilege to close questions with that tag instantly.

Comment: Looks like you have mixed up "score" and "answers". *Answers* = number of non-wiki answers for a tag, *score* = number of *net* upvotes for answers.